# PHP login page without database

Tags: php, login-page

I'm trying to make a test PHP login page which tests whether the user has entered an email and a password and then redirects to another page. I have used a piece of pre-coded login page (HTML part below) in which there is a form made for email and passwords.

```html
               <form action = "" method = "post">
                  <label>Mail:</label><br/>
                  <input type="email" placeholder="Enter your email"><br><br>
                  <label>Password:</label><input type =   "password" name = "password" class = "box" /><br/><br />
                  <input type = "submit" value = " Ok "/><br />
                  <button onclick="location.href='http://www.google.com'" type="button">Ok</button>
               </form>
```

Is it possible to check the entered value on whether it's an email or not?

Comment: I'm new to stackoverflow so maybe I'm not asking the question in a correct way, but I needed to try.

Comment: It can work without DB but you should NOT do that!

Comment: yes. very easily. but could you please first show us what you **tried yourself** so far? and yes you are right, you are asking the question completely wrong. you should have taken **[the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)** and read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first.

Comment: Yes. There are several solutions. Depends, if your created users still have to exist when you come back to your page. If yes, simple .txt documents can be used for saving your data. Otherwise, just work with sessions.

Comment: Yes it can work, u just need a text input validate the email then login

Comment: Love it when they change the question after you have answered it.

Comment: "<button onclick="location.href='http://www.google.com'" type="button">Ok</button>" Why Google? ô.o This should be a simple form submit...
"Is it possible to check the entered value on whether it's an email or not?" yes it is. For example with regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this

after you post your form values to the server page

just use if conditions and pattern match(for email)

```
$password= test_input($_POST["password"]);
if(empty($password)){
$err[]='password Required';
}
if (!preg_match("/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Za-z])[0-9A-Za-z!@#$%]{8,12}$/",$password)) {
  $err[]= "Only letters and white space allowed"; 

}

 if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $err[]= "Email is required";
  } else {
    $email= test_input($_POST["email"]);
    // check if e-mail address is well-formed
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $err[]= "Invalid email format"; 
    }
  }

if(!empty($err)){
 //// echo "email or password error//
var_dump($err); 
}else{
///do your success
}
```

tinker a bit

Answer (score 1):

Not tested but I reckon your looking for something like this ??!

```
<?php
if( isset( $_POST ) )
{
  // Optional
    session_start();
  // End Optional

  $email = FALSE;
  $password = FALSE;

  if( filter_var( $_POST[ 'email' ], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL ) )
  {
    $email = TRUE;
  }
  if( !empty( $_POST[ 'password' ] ) )
  {
    $password = TRUE;
  }

  if( $email && $password )
  {
    // Optional
      $_SESSION[ 'email' ] = $_POST( 'email' );
    // End Optional

    redirect( nextPage.php );
  }
  else
  {
    redirect( login.php );
  }
}
```

It will check if the email is of valid format and that the passwword field is not empty,  if both are correct it will pass the user to the next page otherwise it will go back to the login.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I had to edit the question since it apparently shouldn't had been asked the way it was.